# get same price format in custom category file Magento

Tags: magento, customization, categories, currency

Hi i have a store in dutch language and i a using a euro currency.
in this the price  of product on the magento default category page is shown like

> € 123,00

it contains , but in my custom category file when  fetch the price of product it shows like

> € 123.00

it contains fullstop instead of comma . I need to show comma please suggest me how can i do this .
below is the code i use to echo price

```
$product1->getPrice()
```

in my custom file

thanks

Answer (score -1):

ok i got it and i have use

```
str_replace('.', ',', $product1->getPrice());
```

and it works fine

thanks